# Object is of type 'unknown' from userReducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-reducer

I keep getting the error `Object is of type 'unknown'` from typescript for the `currentUser` state variable I have declared here:

```js
    const initialCurrentUserState: UserInfoObj = localStorageObject["userInfo"]
    const [currentUser, dispatchCurrentUser] = useReducer(currentUserReducer, initialCurrentUserState);

    let loggedIn: boolean = currentUser?.user_id > 0;
```

The error occurs on the final line:
[image: screengrab showing currentUser error]

When I hover over `initialCurrentUserState`, typescript tells me it is of type `UserInfoObj`, but when I hover over any `currentUser` in my code then typescript tells me it is of type `unknown`.

(other code that may be relevant:

```js
export interface UserInfoObj {
    user_id: number;
    firebase_uid: string;
    firebase_id: string;
    email: string;
    dob: string;
    name: string;
    country: null;
    unitcm: number;
    isadmin: boolean;
}

interface Action {
  type: 'UPDATE_USER';
  payload: UserInfoObj;
}

export const currentUserReducer = (state: UserInfoObj, action: Action ) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_USER':
      return {...action.payload}
    default:
      console.log('firing dispatch - state, action:', state, action);
      return state;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I'd like to understand why and how to avoid this error.

Comment: Seems like maybe the problem is that the return value of `currentUserReducer` is not typed.  Have you tried typing it?

Comment: I tried typing the value, like so: ```export const currentUserReducer = (state: UserInfoObj, action: Action ): UserInfoObj => {```

But to no avail. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Oh, just found out that the problem was due to another error: ```Could not find a declaration file for module...``` and I resolved it by going into my tsconfig.json file and changing to ```"target": "ES2018", ``` (from ES2020) and ```    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, ``` though I'm not sure which made the difference.